# Updating SQL Server table columns based on a where clause multiple column null checks

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I'm just curious if there is a more optimized way of performing the following script? There are several columns we are updating and setting to NULL if they are Not already null. I am worried on a 1000+ record table this could take a while to compile all these OR checks.

```
UPDATE center 
SET Email = 'test@test.com', 
    Phone = NULL, 
    FWD = NULL, 
    Default = NULL, 
    Serv = NULL 
WHERE 
    Email IS NOT NULL OR 
    Phone IS NOT NULL OR 
    FWD IS NOT NULL OR 
    Default IS NOT NULL OR
    Mkt IS NOT NULL OR
    Serv IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: All those OR criteria is going to be a single table/clustered index scan - but 1000 rows - absolutely no big deal at all that should be <1s

Comment: That should run very fast.